# Extract Gmail account profile picture to mobile phone

Tags: gmail, profile-picture

How can I retrieve the profile picture that I have on my Gmail account? The original is not in my phone anymore so I would like to download it back so I can have the picture in my smartphone again.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to retrieve the full quality profile picture without ever having uploaded it to Google+, follow these steps:

1. If you have multiple google accounts, open a private window by pressing `CTRL + SHIFT + N` for Chrome or `CTRL + SHIFT + P` for Firefox.
2. Go to any google service such as gmail.com and log into the account you wish to retrieve a profile picture of.
3. Go to https://get.google.com/albumarchive
4. Navigate to Profile photos > profile photos. All the profile pictures of your account can be found here.
5. You can use the triple dot button in the top right corner to either download a single picture, download all pictures or delete individual ones.

This is also where to find your uploaded Google Maps photos, and all Google Hangouts photos. I hope these keywords help future search-wizards having this problem.

---

Update 2023-Dec ([ref](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/), excerpted below):

> Since July 19, 2023, Album Archive is no longer available.
>
> [...]
>
> You can continue to view and manage your photos and videos from these Google products:
>
> - [View and manage your past and current Google account profile photos](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442).
> - [...]

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

Just open the page which has the photo, Press "Print Screen" - a screen-shot of the screen will be copied in your clipboard. Then, go to MS Paint, paste it there crop it and save.

**Option 2**

As mentioned by Bibhas in comment, Go to your Google+ profile. Click on the profile image there. It should give you the option to download. If you do not have a Google Plus account, just create one, it will be created by default with that image, then you can download the image from there and delete your Google+ Account (if you wish).